# Spring,Hibernate : Transactional read only equals to true is not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactional

I am working on a Spring-MVC project, in which I am calling certain methods with annotation `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`. Unfortunately, even after doing this, the contents of Database are getting updated. Don't know how. What am I doing wrong? We had this error for some time, just didn't know that this was triggering changes in Database as we ignored it completely given that the annotation specifically says not to edit, but we were so wrong.

Project properties :

```
<properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.9.Final</hibernate.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <springsecurity.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <spring-platform.version>1.1.3.RELEASE</spring-platform.version>
        <jetty.version>9.2.9.v20150224</jetty.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
```

Code :

```
     @Override
public byte[] createExcelSheetOutOfCanvas(int canvasId) {
    String str = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);

    List<GroupSection> groupSectionList = this.groupSectionService.listGroupSectionByCanvasid(canvasId, false);
    try {
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

        int rowCount = 0;
        Row initialRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount);

        writeNames(initialRow);

        for (GroupSection groupSection : groupSectionList) {

            rowCount++;
            Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);

            writeSectionRow(row, groupSection.getMsectionname());

            List<GroupNotes> groupNotesList = this.groupNotesDAO.listGroupNotesBySectionId(groupSection.getMsectionid());
            for (GroupNotes note : groupNotesList) {
                row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
                writeBook(note, row);
            }
        }


        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/home/deploy/excel/" + str + ".xls")) {
            workbook.write(outputStream);

            Path path = Paths.get("/home/deploy/excel/" + str + ".xls");
            return Files.readAllBytes(path);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

GroupSectionServiceImpl :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class GroupSectionServiceImpl implements GroupSectionService {

  private final GroupSectionDAO groupSectionDAO;

    @Autowired
    public GroupSectionServiceImpl(GroupSectionDAO groupSectionDAO) {
        this.groupSectionDAO = groupSectionDAO;
    }


 @Override
    @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<GroupSection> listGroupSectionByCanvasid(int mcanvasid, boolean masterSectionFlag) {

        List<GroupSection> groupSectionList = this.groupSectionDAO.listGroupSectionByCanvasid(mcanvasid);
// Other method code
}
```

GroupSectionDAOImpl :

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class GroupSectionDAOImpl implements GroupSectionDAO {

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public GroupSectionDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
   @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<GroupSection> listGroupSectionByCanvasid(int mcanvasid) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("From GroupSection as msection where " +
                "msection.currentcanvas.mcanvasid=:mcanvasid and msection.sectionDisabled=false and msection.sectionInActive=false");
        query.setParameter("mcanvasid", mcanvasid);
        return query.list();
    }
}
```

Even, after all, this readOnly= true. How is that when I am calling to the createTheExcel method, values from Database are overwritten.

Controller method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadexcel/{canvasid}") 
    public void downloadExcelSheet(@PathVariable("canvasid") int canvasId, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            GroupCanvas groupCanvas = this.groupCanvasService.getCanvasById(canvasId);
            if (!(groupCanvas == null)) {
                byte[] excelSheet = this.groupNotesService.createExcelSheetOutOfCanvas(canvasId);
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + groupCanvas.getMcanvasname() + ".xls" + "\"");
                response.setContentLength(excelSheet.length);
                FileCopyUtils.copy(excelSheet, response.getOutputStream());
                response.flushBuffer();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it. The readonly is not effective anymore after the transaction has ended. And if there already was an ongoing (non readonly) transaction, the readonly part is ignored.

Comment: @M.Deinum : But I am not calling any code for updating the values, I am only calling code to list the sections as you can see from the DAO method.

Comment: If you are changing things, as long as you are in a transaction those are automatically persisted. You don't need to explicitly call data access code for that for managed entities.

Comment: @M.Deinum : But I am not changing things, if I would have, then it was understandable. And for the very same reason, I have posted the complete excel sheet method in the updated post. If you require any information, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Something must be triggering the change to your objects. If you don't change anything nothing will be persisted to the database. So there must be something in that flow that is changing stuff. Try making the outer most method transactional and readonly. That should result in an error.

Comment: @M.Deinum : The only method outside the excel sheet method is the controller method. I already tried with readOnly=true for the method I posted above, and that stops the database-update, but I just don't understand why this is happening. That is my only question. Updating post with Controller method.

Comment: Then there must be something in that create method or the method that it calls that modifies the entity, maybe a getter with an unwanted side effect.

Comment: FWIW, I think this is less a Spring issue and more of a Hibernate issue.  Perhaps turning on Hibernate logging will give you some insight as to what's going on.

Comment: @Dave : Yes, I saw it in debug logs, that the data-set was update, nothing more useful I could find in the insane amount of logs.

Comment: Are the unwanted changes only related to the GroupSection object graph, is it the only database entity being impacted here?

Comment: Restating my earlier question:  is the `GroupSection` table the only one being erroneously written to?

Comment: @Dave : Yes, only that one is causing problem.

Comment: I see that you call writeBook(note, row), passing it a GroupNote object, and if that object was somehow modified there, that's where GroupNote could be persisted unexpectedly (can't tell, don't have the source for that)... but that isn't what you're seeing!  Darn.  I just don't see anything else that could explain what you're seeing... not with the code I'm looking at.  Sorry.

Comment: Mind telling what exactly is updated?

Answer (score 0):

Wtheter your database gets updated or not has nothing to do with `readOnly = true`, but solely with your logic.  `readOnly = true` is only used by the transaction management.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I don't understand how your answer helps in understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must also make createExcelSheetOutOfCanvas as @Transactional(readOnly=true)